# enviar datos de arduino a servidor web

Tags: arduino

estoy realizando un proyecto de leer una temperatura y enviarla a una base de datos en mi hosting de pago, localmente con un servidor xamp me funciona perfectamente y envia los datos, pero al cambiar tanto el (char server[] = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";) con la ip de mi servidor de hosting y tambien la linea (client.println("Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"); igual con la ip de mi servidor de hosting , no envia nada, ya he mirado un sin numero de foros y paginas y no logro hacerlo funcionar, agradezco si alguien me ayuda, muchas gracias

este es mi codigo de arduino:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //Setting MAC Address

#define DHTPIN 2

#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);


float humidityData;
float temperatureData;

char server[] = "198.136.61.188";
//char server[] = "192.168.0.109";
//char server[] = "www.misterpollo.co";
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,200); 
EthernetClient client; 

/* Setup for Ethernet and RFID */

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("conectado");

  }
  delay(1000);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


/* Infinite Loop */
void loop(){
  humidityData = dht.readHumidity();
  temperatureData = dht.readTemperature(); 
  Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(); 
  delay(3000); // interval

}


  void Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase()   //CONNECTING WITH MYSQL
 {
   if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    
    // Make a HTTP request:
    Serial.print("GET /sensores/anadir.php?humidity=");
    client.print("GET /sensores/anadir.php?humidity=");     //YOUR URL
    Serial.println(humidityData);
    client.print(humidityData);
    client.print("&temperature=");
    Serial.println("&temperature=");
    client.print(temperatureData);
    Serial.println(temperatureData);
    //client.print(" ");      //SPACE BEFORE HTTP/1.1
    client.print(" HTTP/1.0");
    //client.println();
    //client.println("Host: 192.168.0.109");
    client.println("Host: midominio.co");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino 1.0");
    client.println();
    //client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
 }
```

y este el el codigo de anadir.php

```
    <?php
      class dht11{
 public $link='';
 function __construct($temperature, $humidity){
  $this->connect();
  $this->storeInDB($temperature, $humidity);
 }
 
 function connect(){
  $this->link = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx") or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
  mysqli_select_db($this->link,'misterpo_sensores') or die('Cannot select the DB');
 }
 
 function storeInDB($temperature, $humidity){
  $query = "insert into registros set humidity='".$humidity."', temperature='".$temperature."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
 }
 
}
if($_GET['temperature'] != '' and  $_GET['humidity'] != ''){
 $dht11=new dht11($_GET['temperature'],$_GET['humidity']);
}
else
echo "error";



  ?>
```

ahora cuando envio los datos directamente por la url los ingresa sin problemas a la bd.. asi:

https://www.midominio.co/sensores/anadir.php?humidity=50&temperature=34

Comment: La página que indicas (midominio.co) no existe. El server 198.136.61.188 acusa error. ¿Qué nombre/ip tiene el sitio donde quieres subir la info?

Comment: perdon, como tal esa no es mi pagina, es solo un ejemplo, mi dominio es (misterpollo.co), y es tambien es mi duda, porque al intrudicir la ip de mi server no me manda a la pagina sino que me bota ese error.

Comment: Tu servidor Web está validando que las peticiones le lleguen con nombre de host y rechaza las que llegan sólo con la IP. Es razonable en un servidor con múltiples sitios alojados que comparten la IP.

Comment: Parece que `client.print(" HTTP/1.0");` le falta un '\n' al final. Yo diría que es `client.println(" HTTP/1.0");` Eso podría dejar patichueco el header. Lo mismo al mandar la temperatura.

Comment: osea que puede ser problema de mi servidor web?

Comment: No, problema del cliente. Al parecer estás mandando mal el header. Revisa mi anterior comentario.

Comment: la verdad lo he volteado por todo lado y no encuentro el error, ya lo corregi tal cual me comentas y nada, no se porque en localhosto funiona perfecto, que seria cambiando el host a mi ip local.

Comment: Te faltó corregir `client.print(temperatureData);` con `println`

Comment: lo he corregido y nada aun, me estoy volviendo loco, no se que hacer,

Comment: Revisa los logs en el servidor, a ver que llega.

Comment: perdon la ignorancia.. como hago eso?